# How to create a bat file for create one folder in my machine?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, dos

I want to create one bat file for create one folder in my machine. I created like this but its not woking.

```
    @echo off
    "mkdir D:/PHP_Projects/myproject/Release/testfolder";
```

Any body can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove quotes and semicolon, and use backslash, not slash as path separator:

```
@echo off
mkdir D:\PHP_Projects\testprojects\Release\testfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses backslash as path separator. Also, you don't need the quotes and semicolon.

```
mkdir D:/PHP_Projects/myproject/Release/testfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use md like this:

md D:\PHP_Projects\myproject\Release\testfolder